# Capturar y procesar de Información en tiempo real

Tags: java, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación la que requiere analizar capturar y procesar información en tiempo real en java, para solucionar este problema tengo pensado que utilice un hilo para capturar información durante periodos de tiempo X y que la procese para dar una respuesta, el problema es que durante el tiempo que deje de capturar para ponerse a procesar perderá información que no estará capturando, mi idea es usar dos hilos captura/proceso para que mientras uno se ocupa de procesar el otro captura, mi pregunta es:

¿Existe un sistema, modelo o método en la informática para este problema?

Necesito investigarlo para implementar esta función eficientemente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

A un nivel alto de detalle necesitas implementar un patrón de `Productor - Consumidor`.

[image: Esquema Producer-Consumer con BlockingQueue]

[Imagen de esta página](https://www.interviewsansar.com/2014/09/20/java-blockingqueue-example-with-produce-and-consumer-design-pattern/)

Donde un `thread` lee la entrada de datos y los pone en un `buffer` (Podría ser alguno de los `BlockingQueue` de java), y del otro lado uno o más threads que leen la cola y hacen el procesamiento.

Dependiendo de la naturaleza del procesamiento, si el mismo se puede paralelizar, a la salida de la cola podrías usar un `ThreadPoolExecutor` y dividir el trabajo de procesar en diferentes threads, de otro modo, tendrás que limitarte a un solo thread.

Si la diferencia de tiempo sobrante siempre pasa a X, entonces en algún momento se va a llenar el buffer y tendrás perdida de datos. Si en promedio el procesamiento le gana al ingreso de datos entonces el buffer te va a ayudar a no perder datos.

Por último te recomiendo leer sobre "Real Time Java" (RTSJ) dado que hay consideraciones adicionales que hacen a la implementación de un sistema real time que tienen que ver tanto con el sistema operativo como el lenguaje java y la jvm.